# Problem with MySQL - cannot access database

Tags: mysql

My perl script returns this error to me.

`DBI connect('RBPmap:localhost:3306;mysql_read_default_file=/home/mauricio1908/RBPmap/.my.cnf','mauricio1908',...) failed: Access denied for user 'mauricio1908'@'localhost' to database 'RBPmap' at /home/mauricio1908/RBPmap/SQL_RBPMAP.pm line 55. Motifs selection:  SQL_RBPMAP::db: cannot connect to database RBPmap Access denied for user 'mauricio1908'@'localhost' to database 'RBPmap'`

I tried granting access to my 'user'@'localhost' in MySQL using

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SQL_RBPMAP.pm TO 'user'@'localhost';`

For some reason, however, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you actually put `'mauricio1908'`, not `'user'`, correct?

Comment: You might also need to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` in order for the new access settings to become active

Comment: In your `GRANT` statement, instead of `SQL_RBPMAP.pm`, try putting the database identifier - ie `RBPmap.*`